# Button on collection view cell does not react to events

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionViewCell subclass, and a corresponding .xib file associated with it. The cell has some labels and a button with an action attached to it.

The problem is when I tap that button, only:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{/*...*/}
```

gets called.
I guess there should be some way to change the tap event down the chain.

Did anyone face these issues before?
If yes, how did you solve this problem?

Comment: The cell you tapped gets called, yes, but does the actual button ?

Comment: This is actually the problem I mentioned in the question's title.

Comment: @ppalancica, were you ever able to figure this out?  I have the same problem, views with IBActions aren't triggered.  Rather confusing because this only seems to happen with my custom UICollectionViewLayout class.  It never happened with UICollectionViewFlowLayout, which leads me to suspect that flow layout actually handles something so that IBActions are triggered.

Comment: @JoeyCarson I don't remember exactly but I believe it was because of the way I was creating the cell. Just make it a subclass of UICollectionViewCell, and make sure you check "Also create a .xib file". Then you can resize the main view of the generated cell to whatever (I suppose you use Auto-Layout -- so it really does not matter). I also add a main UIView which will resize to the margins of the contentView of the cell, and then add all my UI controls on top of that. I hope it helps. Make sure the File's Owner is set up correctly -- in case you have code already written by someone else.

Comment: Figured I might as well update this thread just because I thought the reason I found wasn't very obvious, at least to me.  The `contentView` frame hadn't been set, so it was `CGRectZero`.  The views that I added were coming up fine rendering because they were subviews of contentView.  But since the superview frame didn't fit the child, the events wouldn't come through.  Setting the appropriate size of the contentView allowed the `IBAction`'s to get through.

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered this issue before when the button isn't in a Collection View Cell in the .xib. If you just have it in a view it won't be in the contentView and won't respond appropriately to events.

Once you do that you should be able to create an IBAction in your UICollectionViewCell subclass and it will be hit.

Comment: The button is there. Actually if I call "[self onGotItButtonTap:nil];" from "layoutSubviews" its action gets called.

Comment: Right, is your .xib a normal view? Or did you delete the view it started with and drag on a collection view cell? I think that is the difference. (at least its an issue I've encountered)

Comment: I added an empty view to the project, then dragged a Collection Reusable View to the Documents Outline. It loads fine, just the tap event is not propagated to the actual button.

Answer (score 0):

How did you add the button, as a subview of of your UICollectionViewCell? You need to do that instead, and add a selector method to your `UIButton` rather than handling it in `didSelectItemAtIndexPath:`.

Here is an example:

In your `- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` or in your custom cells class (Preferably due to efficiency),
Adding the button as a subview should appear as so:

```
self.icon = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

[self.icon addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.icon.frame = CGRectMake(-50, -50, 100, 100);
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];
[self.icon setImage:deleteImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

if (ifYouNeedABOOL == YES) {

    [cell addSubview:self.deleteIcon];
    return cell;
}
```

You can then handle the tap event in your new selector method, `buttonTapped:`.

If you want to stick with adding it in Interface Builder using IBAction, you can utilize tags. Add them to the cells in `cellForItemAtIndexPath:`

Comment: I added it visually, and it also has an IBAction. Not a good idea to add the custom UI creation code inside "collectionView: cellForItemAtIndexPath:" though, as we adhere to Massive-View-Controller this way.

Comment: @ppalancica The code is prototype, just modify your cells creation. You can place it in your custom cells class or where ever is efficient for your specific project as stated. That's just an example of how to do it. Also edited OP for if you want to stick with IBActions.

Comment: My issues is Yes, I know it should work if I do it programmatically, I am wondering if I do it in Interface Builder aka "The Apple way", why it does not work.

Comment: @ppalancica Understood, I'll put my thinking cap on for ya.